# JavaFX jar file throwing exception

Tags: javafx

I've just finished my JavaFX project.
In the src file I've got some folders that each includes different files: FXML, CSS, Class, Files, Controllers.

After I build Artifacts in the IntelliJ, when I run it on cmd, the Jar file throws an exception because it can not find the FXML files!

I've copied the FXML folders next to the Jar file and a folder before it but it doesn't work

I've made packages to be clean but it has made some trouble for me!

[here is a screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpEj0.png)

[And I've made a fatherController that each controller extends from that and it has a method called load page that's how I load my FXML files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvwrj.png)

Comment: How you get the paths of your fxml files ,i mean did you use the relative path or the class path ? can you edit your question and add : packages tree and your stack trace ?

Comment: Please show the code how you are loading your fxml. Also a screenshot to your project structure would help to answer your question.

Comment: Usually you pur resources ***inside*** the jar file not outside of it unless you have a reason to write to them after deploying...

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine I've added Some Pictures see if you can help me! Thanks a lot

Comment: @HarshitaSethi I've added Some Pictures see if you can help me! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the FXMLs like this

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ContactList/FXML/"+fxmlFileName+".fxml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! I shouldn't Address the FXML files like the picture.
instead of "../FXML/example.fxml", Is should use "/FXML/example.fxml".